# The most effective way (linear regression, t-test, etc.) to compare an animal's size to the number of offspring it produces in R

Tags: correlation, biostatistics

So basically, I am studying a population of birds with a focus on their reproductive rates. To that end, I have been using R to compare the wing chord measurements of a given animal to the number of chicks it successfully hatches.

Since the wing chord is more or less continuous but the number of chicks is categorical (0,1,2,3,4,5), a linear regression does not seem to be the most effective way to check for correlation. Does anyone have any suggestion on what to use instead?

Plot made after suggestion in comments:

[image]

Comment: Isn’t number of chicks a count variable that doesn’t necessarily have to be capped at 5? (If your knowledge of the biology gives you a way to know that five is the max, then I might take a different modeling approach, but I have my suspicions that six, seven, and eight (or more) chicks are possible, even if unusual.)

Comment: There are many ways to test for a relationship between wing chord and n chicks, but the first thing to do is to plot your data to explore whether a relationship is apparent: `plot( wingchord ~ factor(nchicks))`.

Comment: @Dave, the species studied is a determinate brooder, so there are exceedingly few cases (~0.1% if that of clutches)

Comment: @GordonSmyth, I did as you suggested and got the following graphic result (https://imgur.com/a/jDk6kFf) considering that the average wing chord measure is ~190 mm am I correct in saying that there is no correlation apparent?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  To me, the plot is sufficient to rule out any worthwhile relationship.

Comment: @Gordon On the contrary, it is impossible to determine from that graphic whether a relationship exists or even to guess at its direction, because it depends on how many observations are represented by each boxplot. For instance, if clutches of 3 and 4 predominate and there are several dozen or more parents in the dataset, then there is a significant (and strong) *negative* correlation; but if clutches of 2 and 3 predominate, the association will be reversed (but likely is nonlinear). For that reason you should *not* rule out the possibility of a "worthwhile" relationship.

Comment: @whuber You have failed to come to grips with the scientific context and the limitations of the available data. There are only 4 distinct x-values (clutch sizes 2, 3, 4 and 5) and the observed distributions of the wing span distribution are almost identical for sizes 2, 4 and 5. Putting a line though sizes 2 and 3 and claiming an overall increasing trend would be unacceptable in any refereed biological journal. One cannot ignore the data for sizes 4 and 5 in that way. It would remain unacceptable even if the linear regression was statistically significant.

Comment: @whuber Putting a decreasing nonlinear curve through points 3 and 4 and claiming an overall decreasing trend would be even sillier. The skew nature of the size 3 boxplot, with no observations above the 3rd quartile, suggests a very small sample size. My general comments would remain however even if the sample size was in the dozens.

Comment: @ActingNaturalist Instead of boxplots, you can display the individual data points like this: `library(beeswarm); beeswarm( wingchord ~ factor(nchicks) )`. The beeswarm package is available from CRAN if you don't have it installed already.